# Rank-$1$ update for Cholesky factor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, cholesky-decomposition

I have covariance matrix known to be

$$K = \sum_{i=1}^Nx_ix_i^T$$

where the dimension of $x$ is big (like $50000$) so I don't want to really compute any outer-product to expand it as a full matrix. Also, I know this covariance matrix is sparse

Since K is guaranteed to be positive-definite, there is a unique Cholesky decomposition :

$$K = L^TL$$

Two questions:

1. is there a way to update $L$ sequentially (update Cholesky factor after seeing each data point).
2. is there approximation of Cholesky that keeps $L$ sparse or low-rank to save memory ?

Comment: So, you see new $x$ values?

Comment: In regard to (1), this is exactly what a rank [one Cholesky update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_update) is for.

Comment: There is such paper: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/161468 from 2004 which considers "Low-Rank Updates for the Cholesky Decomposition"

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of approximation for the covariance matrix in Gaussian Process, to keep it small, when we see a lot of data. If you want to find the decomposition, after seeing new data, the naive way is to just do it again. But one can keep a small subset of the data (the sparsity assumption), and use the remaining data to perform the matrix decomposition. See this recent work: 
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~lowkh/pubs/uai2013.pdf

Comment: that was like a really mathy paper , the core idea is ICF, is it?

Comment: By ICF you mean Incomplete Cholesky Factorization? If so, not really. Most of them is based on the idea that, they project the points in a lower dimensional space. I think, in general, the question you're asking, is not trivial.